# Como adicionar uma coluna de dados com base em outra no excel através do Pandas?

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, pandas

Eu tenho uma planilha com vários dados de importação. O problema é sempre o formato como os dados vêm.
Por exemplo, eu tenho uma coluna chamada "Bens Importados" que tem valores como o abaixo:

> 1 X 40 CONTAINERS CONTAINING 40 BAGS OF FLUTRIAFOL TECNICO SINON
> FLUTRIAFOL 97% TECH

Por esta descrição, eu sei que o produto importado neste caso é o *Flutriafol*.
No excel, eu usei a combinação abaixo para pegar os valores desta coluna e retornar somente o produto em outra:

```
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("FLUTRIAFOL", colunaX)), "Flutriafol", "Não identificado")
```

Funcionou bem, mas eu queria fazer isso agora no *Python*, pois parece mais adequado quando são muitas as possibilidades de valores (e é também o meu único recurso disponível hoje).

Já sei como fazer o upload da minha base no *Python* e importar o *pandas* para me ajudar com o tratamento, mas não faço ideia de qual função/comando eu poderia usar para fazer esta operação de achar um valor numa coluna e retornar ele em outra.

Answer (score 1):

Para criar uma coluna baseada em outra siga os passos abaixo:

### Criar Dataframe

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"compras": ["1 X 40 CONTAINERS CONTAINING 40 BAGS OF FLUTRIAFOL TECNICO SINON FLUTRIAFOL 97% TECH", "OUTRA COMPRA QUALQUER"]})

>>> df
                                             compras
0  1 X 40 CONTAINERS CONTAINING 40 BAGS OF FLUTRI...
1                              OUTRA COMPRA QUALQUER
```

### Nova coluna

```
>>> df["nova_coluna"] = df.apply(lambda x: "FLUTRIAFOL" if "FLUTRIAFOL" in x["compras"] else "Não identificado", axis=1)

>>> df
                                             compras       nova_coluna
0  1 X 40 CONTAINERS CONTAINING 40 BAGS OF FLUTRI...        FLUTRIAFOL
1                              OUTRA COMPRA QUALQUER  Não identificado
```

A função lambda poderia ser substituída por uma função definida explicitamente conforme abaixo:

```
>>> def eh_fluriafol(row):
...     if "FLUTRIAFOL" in row["compras"]:
...         return "FLUTRIAFOL" 
...     else:
...         return "Não identificado"

>>> df["nova_coluna1"] = df.apply(eh_fluriafol, axis=1)

>>> df
                                             compras       nova_coluna      nova_coluna1
0  1 X 40 CONTAINERS CONTAINING 40 BAGS OF FLUTRI...        FLUTRIAFOL        FLUTRIAFOL
1                              OUTRA COMPRA QUALQUER  Não identificado  Não identificado
```

Espero que ajude

Comment: Obrigado, Paulo!

Answer (score 0):

Importando as libs

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Criando o df teste

```
conteudo = ['1 X 40 CONTAINERS 40 BAGS OF FLUTRIAFOL TECNICO SINON FLUTRIAFOL 97% TECH',
            '1 X 20 CONTAINERS 20 BAGS OF BLABLABLA TECNICO SINON BLABLABLA TECH',
            '1 X 10 CONTAINERS 10 BAGS OF BLABLABLA TECNICO SINON BLABLABLA TECH']


df = pd.DataFrame({"Dados_de_compra": conteudo })
```

Utilizando o np.where, onde existir a palavra FLUTRIAFOL ele irá retornar 'FLUTRIAFOL', caso contrario irá retornar 'Não identificado'

```
df['Variavel_Resposta'] = np.where(df['Dados_de_compra'].str.contains('FLUTRIAFOL'), 
                                   'FLUTRIAFOL','Não identificado')
```

Saída

```
                                     Dados_de_compra    Variavel_Resposta
0   1 X 40 CONTAINERS 40 BAGS OF FLUTRIAFOL TECNIC...   FLUTRIAFOL
1   1 X 20 CONTAINERS 20 BAGS OF BLABLABLA TECNICO...   Não identificado
2   1 X 10 CONTAINERS 10 BAGS OF BLABLABLA TECNICO...   Não identificado
```

---

**Update**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

database = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CaiqueBarrreto/agroci/main/basePY.csv?token=ALHIP5DQQC23APAHTA2VKNTADKLSK")
database['variavel_resposta'] = np.where(database['Goods Shipped'].str.contains('FLUTRIAFOL'), 'FLUTRIAFOL', 'NID')
```

Comment: Imonferrari, segui a metodologia do np.where adaptada à minha situação, mas por algum motivo não está rodando como o teu. No meu caso, eu tenho um arquivo csv, coloco ele na base, extraio uma das colunas dele e a transformo em uma lista, aí sigo conforme indicado por você. No output está somente emitindo uma linha:
 dados_de_compra variavel_resposta
0 Good... FLUTRIAFOL

Comment: @CaiqueBarretoVocê transforma a coluna em uma lista? Poderia colocar aqui o código utilizado?

Comment: @imonferrari, se eu postar o código como uma resposta à minha pergunta você consegue visualizar? Pelo comentário o código fica ilegível hahah. Postei como respota à pergunta

Answer (score 0):

@imonferrari, este é o código que eu estou utilizando:

import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

#importar a fonte de dados

database = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CaiqueBarrreto/agroci/main/basePY.csv?token=ALHIP5DQQC23APAHTA2VKNTADKLSK")

#isolar a coluna de interesse na planilha csv

database_goodshipped = database.iloc[:, [26]]

#database_goodshipped

#transformar a coluna isolada em lista

conteudo = [database_goodshipped]

#executar o np.where
df = pd.DataFrame({"dados_de_compra": conteudo})

df['variavel_resposta'] = np.where(df['dados_de_compra'].str.contains('FLUTRIAFOL'),
'FLUTRIAFOL', 'NID')

df

No output, acabo ficando com apenas uma linha:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

agradeço à ajuda : )

Comment: `database = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CaiqueBarrreto/agroci/main/basePY.csv?token=ALHIP5DQQC23APAHTA2VKNTADKLSK")
database['variavel_resposta'] = np.where(database['Goods Shipped'].str.contains('FLUTRIAFOL'), 'FLUTRIAFOL', 'NID')`